# CodeIgniter image upload and resize failing

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload, image-manipulation

I am really struggling with my CodeIgniter script for uploading, resizing and cropping profile images for users. In the end, I want to upload the image with an encrypted name, resize it and save it twice (once as a thumbnail and once as a medium sized image), and then delete the original file. However, I guess I'm really missing something, because I can't get the first upload resize process to work. I definitely have an error somewhere in the code (error to follow code), but I think I may have a gap in my understanding of the logic here. Who knows? Any feedback is extremely appreciated .

```
public function image() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './temp_images/'; // This directory has 777 access
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width']  = '0'; // For unlimited width
    $config['max_height']  = '0'; // For unlimited height
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $image_data_array = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        foreach ($image_data_array as $image_data){
            $raw_name = $image_data['raw_name'];
            $file_ext = $image_data['file_ext'];
        }

        $file_name = $raw_name . $file_ext;
        $image_path = 'temp_images/' . $file_name;
        $new_path = 'image/profile/'; // This directory has 777 access

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd';
        $config['source_image'] = $image_path;
        $config['new_image'] = $new_path;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width']     = 140;
        $config['height']   = 140;
        $config['quality'] = '80%'; 

        $new_name = $new_path . $raw_name . $file_ext;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        // The following is just to test that it worked:

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()) { 
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            echo 'source: ' . $config['source_image'] . '<br />';
            echo 'new: ' . $config['new_image'] . '<br />';
        }
        else {
            echo "<img src='" . base_url() . $new_name . "' />";
        }

        $this->image_lib->clear();

    }
}
```

The upload process works fine. Even the resizing worked when I just called `$this->image_lib->resize()`. It was when I tried the error-catching that it started yelling at me. I double-verified that both of the temp_images and image/profile have 777 permissions (as aforementioned, the upload and resize actually worked at one point). Here is the error produced:

```
Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.
source: temp_images/8ee1bab383cf941f34218f7535d5c078.jpg
new: image/profile/
```

Comment: When creating the image in 140x140 the $config['new_image'] must be the full path of the image including file name, "image/profile/$filename".
$filename being something like "image.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

Never really used CI before and can't see the details of your code.

- First, check the permission that set on the folder - you are trying to upload to. Also try to use the full server path.
- Second, see if you have PHP image extensions such as GD, ImageMagick enabled.

Answer (score 1):

i've tried this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation/)

it works well for image upload and create thumbs folder for the resizing image...

Answer (score 0):

Please update the new_image value by including the filename also.

```
$config['new_image'] = 'image/profile/' . $filename;
```